# How can I call numberOfSectionsInTableView multiple times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have implemented 3 UIButtons that represents 3 dates. Depending on which button is selected, I want to display a different UITableView, which represents the selected day schedule of events.

Depending on which button is selected, I hide the other 2 table views.

I have 3 UITableViews, each of which is contained within each UIView, for example, UITableView1 is contained within UIView1 for the selected UIButton1.

How can it be possible to call numberOfSectionsInTableView to return the number of sections depending on which button is selected?

I have something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (date1Selected == YES && date2Selected == NO && date3Selected == NO)
    {
        return [date1 count];
    }
    else if (date1Selected == NO && date2Selected == YES && date3Selected == NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"test");
        return [date2 count];
    }
}
```

However, it never seems to enter the else if.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can do this by calling: [myTableView reloadData];

Comment: for each button click event, reloadData will do your requirement.

Comment: where would that be called? in each if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on click of UIButton1

[UITableView1 reloadData]

on click of `UIButton2`

[UITableView2 reloadData]

on click of `UIButton3`

[UITableView3 reloadData]

Comment: one more thing I wanna tell you that instead of 
if (date1Selected == YES && date2Selected == NO && date3Selected == NO)
    {
        return [date1 count];
    }
you can easily write this
if ([tableView isEqual:UITableView1])
    {
        return [date1 count];
    }
if ([tableView isEqual:UITableView2])
    {
        return [date2 count];
    }
no need to take bool for this

Answer (score 1):

Call `[tableView reloadData]`. The table will pick up all changes in your data source.

Comment: I have 3 different tableViews, where would I call reloadData for each tableView?

Comment: Only the one that is visible on the screen currently.

Answer (score 0):

reload table view `[tableView reloadData]`