# Call numberOfSectionsInTableView after insertion a row inside the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, core-data

what I am trying to do is inserting data from **Core Data** inside UITableView everything is going to be fine except one trick if there is no data inside Core Data I only display a label message that said no data is inserted yet I already made many researches about this topic and how to implemented.

I found this 
[iOS Programming 101: Implementing Pull-to-Refresh and Handling Empty Table](http://www.appcoda.com/pull-to-refresh-uitableview-empty/) which not a complete tutorial and also i search on stack for some examples i just found [How can I call numberOfSectionsInTableView multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315455/how-can-i-call-numberofsectionsintableview-multiple-times)

**here is my full implementation of code:**

```
    - (IBAction)refresh:(id)sender {

        [self getAllReservationHistory];
        [sender endRefreshing];

    }        

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier =  @"Cell";
        EntryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        ReservationEntity *reservationEntry  = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell configureCellForEntry:reservationEntry];

        return cell;
    }  

    -(NSFetchRequest *) entryListFetchRequest {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest  = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Reservations"];
        [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:10];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"reservationID" ascending:NO]];
        return fetchRequest;

    }


    // this method is used to fetch the data //
    -(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultController {
        if(_fetchedResultController != nil)
            return _fetchedResultController;
        CoreData *coreDataStack = [CoreData defaultStack];
        NSFetchRequest *fechtRequest = [self entryListFetchRequest];
        _fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fechtRequest managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        _fetchedResultController.delegate = self;
        return _fetchedResultController;

    }

    //- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    //heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //    //differ between your sections or if you
    //    //have only on section return a static value
    //    return 50;
    //}

    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"details"])
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
            UINavigationController *naviagationController = segue.destinationViewController;
            DetailedHistoryViewController *detailedHisotryViewController = (DetailedHistoryViewController *) naviagationController.topViewController;
            detailedHisotryViewController.entry = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    }


    -(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
    {
        switch (type) {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] > 10) {
                    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    /*****************************************************************************************/


    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];
    }


   - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1) {
        return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
    }
    return nil;
}    

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


//
//- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//    if(footerView == nil) {
//        footerView  = [[UIView alloc] init];
//        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
//        button.layer.cornerRadius = (button.frame.size.width + button.frame.size.height)/ 2.0f;
//        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0/255.0 green:76.0/255.0 blue:136.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];
//        //the button should be as big as a table view cell
//        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(300, 0, 50, 50)];
//        
//        //set title, font size and font color
////        [button setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//        [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
//        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//        
//        //set action of the button
//        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(AddReservation)
//         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//        
//        //add the button to the view
//        [footerView addSubview:button];
//    }
//    
//    //return the view for the footer
//    return footerView;
//}

//-(void) AddReservation {
//    NSLog(@"Bla");
//}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    CoreData *ch = [CoreData defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Reservations" inManagedObjectContext:ch.managedObjectContext]];

    [request setIncludesSubentities:NO]; //Omit subentities. Default is YES (i.e. include subentities)

    NSError *err;
    NSUInteger count = [ch countForFetchRequest:request error:&err];
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)count);
    if(count != 0)
    {
        return self.fetchedResultController.sections.count;
        //            return 10;

    }


    UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    messageLabel.text = @"No data is currently available. Please pull down to refresh.";
    messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    messageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Italic" size:20];
    [messageLabel sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = messageLabel;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id< NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultController sections][section];

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    //    return 10;
}
```

**Full Description:**

Here is in details what I am trying to do is :

- If there is no data inside the core data the UITableView display a label message " that there is no data" or whatever the message is and
- After inserting the first reservation this label message should disappear and displaying the reservation data

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your numberOfSectionsInTableView after your if condition

```
   if(count != 0)
{
    return self.fetchedResultController.sections.count;
    //            return 10;

}
 else {
 return 1;
}
```

and in your numberOfRowsInTableView return 1 similarly

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath check if

```
 id< NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultController sections][section];

if([sectionInfo objects]>0)
{// display cell
}
else
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueCellUsingResusableIdentifier:@"cell" atIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *label;
if(!cell)
{
  cell = [[UITableviewCell alloc]initWithCellIdentifier:@"cell"];
  label =[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,50)];
}
  label.text = @"No data is currently available. Please pull down to refresh.";
 }
}
```

Comment: after trying to implement your solution i got an error tell me that use of undeclared sections
 id< NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultController sections][section];

Comment: I've used code of numberOfRowsInSection to check if there are any rows or not

Comment: i mean inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: not the problem with sectionInfo the problem is with the first line after  "and in CellForRowAtIndexPath Check if "  id< NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultController sections][section];
the error is undeclared variable section

Comment: change section to [indexPath.section]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86775/discussion-between-zakaria-darwish-and-misha).